# Selenium Webdriver can't find the button element on the webpage

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click on Case Registration which is a button on webpage, have tried with xpath, cssseslector, id but didn't helped, here's the html code:

```
<div class="btnimgdiv" style="top:0; left:105; width:20; height:18;">
    <img class="btnimg" style="top:1; left:2; width:16; height:15;" alt="" arimgcenter="0" artxt="" aralttxt="0" src="../../../../imagepool/32ffffffb81fffffffc45effffffdbffffff981849ffffffceffffffc0fffffffc2dfffffffe7e2"></img>
</div>
<div class="btntextdiv" style="top:0; left:0; width:103; height:18;">
    <div class="f1" style="width: 103px;">

        Case registration   

    </div>
</div>
```

Page loads and no click seem, eclipse shows NoSuchElement found exception.

can somebody pls suggest some alternative?

thanks,
jaggs

Comment: Which XPaths and CSS selectors have you tried?

Comment: please post you xpath here

Comment: Is your registration element in an iframe? More of parent html would help wrap functional context around the nosuchelement exception

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

XPath:

```
 //div[@class='btntextdiv']/div
 //div[contains(text(),'Case registration')]
```

CSS:

```
 .btntextdiv>div
```

Comment: I will try that Rishi.